# Add OAuth for a web app stored in Azure VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an Azure VM which contains the deployment of an ASP.NET Web Application. The way that I deploy the web app is trough Web Deploy and files got copied into the **C:\inetpub\WebApplication1** after the deployment is done.

Current Authentication is **NLTM**, for that, the **web.config** file looks like this in the authentication section.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
        <providers>
          <clear />
          <add value="NTLM" />
          <add value="Negotiate" />
        </providers>
      </windowsAuthentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And this is how the Authentication looks on the Azure VM IIS
[image: Configurator Editor]

[image: Configurator Editor2]

How can I switch into OAuth and use Azure Active Directory as the Authorization mechanism to access to the Web App?

So far, I went into the **Azure Active Directory** in the **Azure Portal** and Registered a new Application (**Application Type = Web App / API**) and then set the Home Page with the main page of the Web Application (http://azureMachineName:60)

This registration process generated an Object Id and Application Id. At this point I don't really know how to hook this up with my Web App solution.

This is how the Startup class looks like

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

    }
}
```

And inside of the App_Start, I only have the following clases:

```
BundleConfig.cs
IdentityConfig.cs
RouteConfig.cs
```

Any idea how I can switch into OAuth and use AAD?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding that you want to use AAD instead of original authentication, If it is that case, we could add the following code. It is the snippet of the [demo code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) that using the **ASP.Net OpenID Connect OWIN** middleware.

```
 // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
 // The Metadata Address is used by the application to retrieve the signing keys used by Azure AD.
 // The AAD Instance is the instance of Azure, for example public Azure or Azure China.
 // The Authority is the sign-in URL of the tenant.
 // The Post Logout Redirect Uri is the URL where the user will be redirected after they sign out.
 //
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```